# How to remove a parent entity if a child collection is empty?

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine

I have 2 entities: `Game` and `Product`. A `Game` has a One to Many relationship with `Product`.

`Game` is defined as

```
class Game
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="game")
     */
    private $products;
}
```

In order to delete Game when $games->getProducts() is empty, I created an onFlush listener. The issue is that the count of products is the count before the changes are actually applied. This will work fine if I remove entities one by one, but will fail if I remove 2 or more products at once as I cannot confirm that collection is empty, any idea how I could achieve this?

The Listener is defined as such:

```
class ChainDeletionListener {

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event): void {

        $em = $event->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entity) {
            // We check if the deleted entities are Product
            if ($entity instanceof Product) {
                /** @var Product $entity */
                $game = $entity->getGame();

                if (sizeof($game->getProducts()) === 1) {
                    // If the Product we are removing is the last one, we also remove the Game
                    $em->remove($game);
                    $uow->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity)), $entity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: have you tried setting the orphanRemoval option? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetomany

Comment: The orphan removal won't work here as I am trying to delete the game when there is no attached products anymore. I believe oprhanRemoval would work to automatically delete Product which no longer have a Game associated with them

Comment: The description is fairly explicit that the entity is removed when all owning instances are disconnected. since the products are the owning side (owning side has "inversedBy"), I'd rather assume the exact opposite from what you claim. However, I don't want to force a 30 character solution on you, when you've set your mind on the 15 LOC solution.

Comment: I appreciate your time answering @Jakumi but my understanding is that the orphanRemoval will remove any Products if they are not linked to a Game (One Game for Many Products), which is not my use case. In the link provided, it seems the Many side will be removed.

Comment: mmmh, I'm afraid you're actually correct. In that case there's a straight forward approach (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your @OneToMany annotation, add "cascade" attribute:

```php
class Game
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="game", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $products;
}
```

Comment: I believe this will delete all Products if a Game is deleted. My use case is to delete the Game if I delete the last Product associated with it. What do you think?

Comment: All right i understand, i would suggest to add annotation on Product entity too but i'm not sure it will fix, you can try.
Is `$game->getProducts()` an ArrayCollection ? If yes, maybe the siezof() function is not the solution, try with `if ($game->getProducts()->isEmpty())` 
Look: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/latest/index.html#isempty
(but only if you are using ArrayCollection for children entity)

Comment: This is indeed an ArrayCollection. I could use $game->getProducts()->count() instead of sizeof but the returned results are the same. Similarly, isEmpty returns false as the count is still not 0.

Comment: When I look at the entity scheduled for deletion, I see the Product but I can see the $game->getProducts() is not computed by Doctrine.

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to get Game entity independently like something like this : 
`$game = $em->getRepository(Game::class)->find($entity->getGame()->getId());`

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach would be to actually load the game entity with its products collection and remove the products in that collection alongside.

```php
class ChainDeletionListener {

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event): void {

        $em = $event->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entity) {
            // We check if the deleted entities are Product
            if ($entity instanceof Product) {
                /** @var Product $entity */
                $game = $entity->getGame();

                $game->removeProduct($entity); // <-- NEW, might have to implement

                if (sizeof($game->getProducts()) === 0) { // <-- NEW changed size: 0
                    // If the Product we are removing is the last one, we also remove the Game
                    $em->remove($game);
                    $uow->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity)), $entity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes a fault-tolerant removal Game::removeProduct(Product) implementation. The obvious downside is the games' collections always being loaded. I don't see a *safe* way around that.

Alternatively, you could go post-flush and check for games with zero products.